# Is 来自 a 口语 or 书面语?

Tags: meaning, usage, sentence-structure

Is 来自 used in daily conversations? For example, if I want to say "I come from Malaysia." Should the sentence be 我来自马来西亚。or 我是从马来西亚来的。?

Comment: 来自 is mostly used for 书面语。

Comment: There can't be a strict line, that's not how human language work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people, 来自(came from) is more literary than colloquial, As your example stated 我来自马来西亚 is more literary  and 我是从马来西亚来的 is more colloquial

However, for objects, 来自 is a common preposition for 'from' in day to day speech

Example:

這些橙**来自**加州 - These oranges are **from** California (the oranges didn't come here on their own, someone delivered them)

這病毒**來自**非洲 - This virus is **from** Africa (the virus didn't travel on it's own, someone carried it)